# SQL group into ranges the sum of values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an table which contains inventory information for some items.

| AGENT_ID | ITEM_ID | WAREHOUSE_ID | QTY | BATCH | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IT101 | 1 | 10 | B001 | 5 |
| 100 | IT101 | 2 | 13 | B002 | 8 |
| 100 | IT101 | 1 | 15 | B003 | 18 |
| 100 | IT102 | 3 | 10 | B005 | 42 |

The *age* column indicates how long the items had been in the warehouse. I need to generate an output which contains how the items had aged in the warehouse. These need to be summed into ranges based on the age. Below is an example output.

| AGENT_ID | ITEM_ID | WAREHOUSE | R1(1-10) | R2(11-20) | R3(21<) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | IT101 | 1 | 10 | 15 | 0 |
| 100 | IT101 | 2 | 13 | 0 | 0 |
| 100 | IT102 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 10 |

The first row in the second table represents that *10* items of *IT101* had been in warehouse 1 for a period of (1-10) days, 15 items been in warehouse 1 for (11-20) days and so on.

Is there a way to group from agent, item, warehouse ids and sum the item quantity at the same time grouping it into ranges?
The first table may contain several millions of records. Tried this with some inner queries but it takes so much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use conditional aggregation:

```
select AGENT_ID, ITEM_ID, WAREHOUSE
      , sum(case when age between 1 and 10 then QTY end) "R1(1-10)"
      , sum(case when age between 11 and 20 then QTY end) "R2(11-20)"
      , sum(case when age > 20 then QTY end) "R3(21<)"
From table 
group by AGENT_ID, ITEM_ID, WAREHOUSE
```